# submenu gets hidden thought the cursor is over the menu

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a very simple which i created many times before but this time i'm facing a problem which is the submenu gets hidden though the cursor is over it here's the js code

```
$(".menu").mouseenter(function(){
$(this).children("div").slideDown(400);
console.log("inside submenu");
});

$(".menu").mouseleave(function(){
$(this).children("div").slideUp(400);
console.log("out of submenu");
});
```

HTML code

```
<div class="menu"> 
<a href="#">main item</a> 
<div class="submenu"> 
<a href="#">item</a> 
<a href="#">item</a> 
<a href="#">item</a> 
<a href="#">item</a> 
</div> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
nav .menu{margin-left: 2px; float: right; height: 68px; width: 138px; 
position: relative;}

nav .submenu {display: none; width: 409px; position: absolute; right: 0; 
top: 68px; min-height: 1px; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9); padding: 10px 0 15px 0; }
```

you can find the menu here http://mawk3y.net/sky/ the page is in Arabic but the menu link is in englich

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions and show all relevant code within the OP, not relying on external links.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".submenu" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).show();
  }, function() {
    $( this ).slideUp( 400 );
  }
);
```

Comment: not working but thanks anyway

Comment: please add all menu code

Comment: <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">main item</a>
        <div class="submenu">
            <a href="#">item</a>
            <a href="#">item</a>
            <a href="#">item</a>
            <a href="#">item</a>

        </div>
    </div>

Comment: re-edit your question including styles